# OpenFIGI API and CORS

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm trying to interface the OpenFIGI API from a browser application, which I am hosting locally by using node's http-server. My POST-request looks like this

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping';
  var params = [{"idType": "ID_WERTPAPIER", "idValue": "851399", "exchCode": "US"}];
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/json");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
  xhr.send(params);
```

But all I am getting is the errors

> - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
> - XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:20000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Since I've been trying around with different ways to do the request and different settings, I am wondering - is that even possible? Am I missing something w.r.t. request? I looked at the OpenFIGI API examples, but I could not find any other (CORS) settings there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenFIGI API responses don’t include the `Access-Control-*` response headers needed to make browsers allow your frontend JavaScript code to access the responses. So if you want to send the requests from your frontend code, your only option is use a proxy.

To try making the request through a public CORS proxy, try changing your code to:

```
var url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
   + 'https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping';
```

That sends the request through https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com, which forwards the request to `https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping` and then receives the response. The `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` backend then adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response and finally passes that back to your requesting frontend code.

The browser will then allow your frontend code to access the response, because that response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what the browser sees.

You can also easily set up your own CORS proxy using https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/

For details about what browsers do when you send cross-origin requests from frontend JavaScript code using XHR or the Fetch API or AJAX methods from JavaScript libraries—and details about what response headers must be received in order for browsers to allow frontend code to access the responses—see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Comment: I am trying to run lz129's code with @sideshowbarker's fix.

The fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/theo/qvq4xLgy/

Every time I run the code there is a 400 error. Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: @sideshowbarker - looks like adding the apostrophe-s I added after your name prevented you from being notified of my previous message. Would you kindly have a look at the message just above this one?

Comment: @Theo No idea. You probably want to post that as a separate question. Off the top of my head: if that getting a 400 error back might indicate is, the JSON data you’re posting is not in the format that API endpoint expects. Try  posting the same data using curl or postman or whatever, and if you also get a 400 back when you do that, then you know the problem is with your data and not with the particular mechanism you’re using to post it.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thanks for the speedy reply. The same data works just fine with Curl. I will repost as separate question.

Comment: @sideshowbarker the jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/theo/qvq4xLgy/ - works now. All it needed was the params to be contained in quotes.